# Multiple Queues with same binding key and one consumer

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a scenario as below

[image]

Exchange is of type "topic" and i have two queues(queue1 and queue2) binded to it with routing key #.

Each queue is having 1 consumer. Now, when i send a message from publisher both queues are getting my message since its binded to routing key # .

Is there any way, we can send messages to only one queue on round robin basis ?

Since, each message is getting into both queues , i am getting duplication of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for round robin consuming you shoud see this pattern:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

So basically you publish to one queue and then you add consumers to the same queue.

through the `QoS = 1` you have the round-robin. In this way you can add more consumers without create new queues

Comment: i read that tutorial. I am exactly looking for 2 queues with same binding key , but not getting duplicate messages (i.e. the message goes to any one queue , but not both). whether is it possible ?

Comment: No, with 2 queues and same routing-key, it is not possible.